# Fix the div vertically but 30px away horizontally from it's container

Tags: html, css, css-position

There is a parent container of relative width (50%) so that it responds to the size of the screen.

Now, I want a button at the bottom right corner of this parent container which stays ***fixed vertically***. It works with `position: fixed` but then when i view it on different devices, i cannot get it to be positioned horizontally.

This is my html and CSS

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="button"></div>
</div>

.container {
  position: relative;
  height: 2000px;
  width: 40%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background: yellow;
}

.button {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  background: red;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 20px;
  right: calc(50% - 190px);
}
```

Here is the link to codepen http://codepen.io/anon/pen/VmggdO

This looks fine but when you resize the screen horizontally, the button should stay just 30px inside of the yellow container horizontally - How do i achieve that? REMEMBER - THE BUTTON NEEDS TO STAY FIXED VERTICALLY WHEN YOU SCROLL!

Comment: Can you explain what you want to happen when you resize the window? And which resize? width/height?

Comment: Yes - When you resize the window horizontally, i want the red button to stay just 30px inside the yellow container.

Comment: Does the html structure must be the one you provided?

Comment: Position fixed positions relative to the browser window, not the parent element. I think that's your problem.

Comment: I want to keep the button fixed vertically- positioning it absolute moves the button when you scroll up and down

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using position absolute worked for me

```
.button {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  background: red;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 20px;
  right: 30px;
}
```

**EDIT:**

With the new requirements of "THE BUTTON NEEDS TO STAY FIXED VERTICALLY WHEN YOU SCROLL", this can be achieved by changing the html to this:

```
<div class="container">
</div>
<div class="button-container">
  <div class="button"></div>
</div>
```

and the CSS to this:

```
.container {
  position: relative;
  height: 2000px;
  width: 40%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background: yellow;
}

.button {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  background: red;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  float: right;
  margin-right: 30px;
  z-index: 100;
}

.button-container{
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0px;
  width: 40%;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
```

See the updated code pen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/mOvvgJ

Comment: I want to keep that button fixed vertically - that is if you scroll the page, the button stays at the bottom of the screen - so, position absolute doesn't work

Comment: @Ishita, i have updated my answer to your updated requirements.  It does involve a slight change to the html but i believe it is necessary to do so.

Comment: @Ishita, ok it's updated now and should be correct for what you want, sorry about that :)

Comment: Thank You sir - this is exactly what i wanted :)